# Intel hex file to UU-encode format for LPC2148

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader, lpc

I'm writing the application for OSX which needs to send a new program (compiled lpc code) via Wifi to microcontroller and there i will use built in `In-Application-Programming` interface to program flash memory. Similar thing i have done in a past for `Atmel AVR` where i sent .hex file and write it to flash memory.

I saw that NXP LPC is using some `UU-encode` format (3 binary bytes to 4 ascii bytes) and little different packaging of the data. What i dont know is how do i get this `UU-encode` file? Do i need to make converter for `HEX2UUE`?

I'm using Keil uVision compiler. Any setting there to produce it ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Is this what you are looking for: http://superuser.com/questions/120796/os-x-base64-encode-via-command-line

Comment: No. That is something different. I'm looking for a way to convert intel hex format to uu-encode format. Both formats are used for storing compiled microcontroller code. It is possible to setup linker to output hex file but for uu-encode format ive never heard before today :-)

Comment: So if you have a Intel-hex to binary and a binary to uu-encoder you're done, right?

Comment: I'm setting up a git server and it is far from done, but here is a link to a perl script I wrote to decode IntelHex. You should be able to pipe that into uuencode. http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=decodeIntelHex;a=blob;f=decodeIntelHex;h=2c6fc2bf54e019d37a6de8d2d40f07f2121e7130;hb=8e966feb8360085e00176ad37215413760c7513a